# How to code shell script with command line arguments like -la

Tags: shell-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I handle switches in a shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20975/how-do-i-handle-switches-in-a-shell-script)

I know how to deal with simple arguments $1-$9 but I don't know how to code it with such as `-la`, for example `ls -la`. Could you show me example?

Comment: See also this [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20975/9537).