# bash how to remove options from parameters after processing

Tags: bash, arguments

I remember having seen somewhere a `bash` script using `case` and `shift` to walk through the list of positional parameters, parse flags and options with arguments when it encounters them, and removes them after parsing to leave only the bare arguments, which are later processed by the rest of the script.

For example, in parsing the command line of `cp -R file1 -t /mybackup file2 -f`, it would first walk through the parameters, recognize that the user has requested to descend into directories by `-R`, specified the target by `-t /mybackup` and to force copying by `-f`, and remove those from the list of parameters, leaving the program to process `file1 file2` as the remaining arguments.

But I don't seem to be able to remember/find out whatever script I saw whenever. I'd just like to be able to do that. I have been googling around various sites and append a list of relevant pages I examined.

A question on this website specifically asked about "order-independent options" but both the single answer and the answer of the question it was dupped to does not consider cases like the above where the options are mixed with normal arguments, which I presume was the reason for the person to specifically mention *order-independent* options.

Since `bash`'s built-in `getopts` seems to stop at the first non-option argument, it does not seem to be sufficient as a solution. This is why the Wooledge BashFAQ's page (see below) explains how to rearrange the arguments. But I'd like to avoid creating multiple arrays in case the argument list is quite long.

Since `shift` does not support popping individual arguments off the middle of the parameter list, I am not sure what is a straightforward way to implement what I am asking.

I'd like to hear if anyone has any solutions to removing arguments from the middle of the parameter list without creating a whole new array.

Pages that I've already seen:

- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ComplexOptionParsing#Rearranging_arguments
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035
- [Using getopts in bash shell script to get long and short command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options/7680682#7680682)
- http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams
- http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial
- [bash argument case for args in $@](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062895/bash-argument-case-for-args-in)
- [What is the canonical way to implement order independent options in bash scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49096/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-implement-order-independent-options-in-bash-scripts)
- [How do I handle switches in a shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20975/how-do-i-handle-switches-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: Once I need something complicated, I switch from bash to Perl.

Answer (score 11):

POSIXly, the parsing for options should stop at `--` or at the first non-option (or non-option-argument) argument whichever comes first. So in

```
cp -R file1 -t /mybackup file2 -f
```

that's at `file1`, so `cp` should recursively copy all of `file1`, `-t`, `/mybackup` and `file2` into the `-f` directory.

GNU `getopt(3)` however (that GNU `cp` uses to parse options (and here you're using GNU `cp` since you're using the GNU-specific `-t` option)), unless the `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable is set, accepts options after arguments. So it is actually equivalent to POSIX option style parsing's:

```
cp -R -t /mybackup -f -- file1 file2
```

The `getopts` shell built-in, even in the GNU shell (`bash`) only handles the POSIX style. It also doesn't support long options or options with optional arguments.

If you want to parse the options the same way as GNU `cp` does, you'll need to use the GNU `getopt(3)` API. For that, if on Linux, you can use the enhanced `getopt` utility from `util-linux` ([that enhanced version of the `getopt` command](http://software.frodo.looijaard.name/getopt/) has also been ported to some other Unices like [FreeBSD](http://portsmon.freebsd.org/portoverview.py?category=misc&portname=getopt)).

That `getopt` will rearrange the options in a canonical way which allows you to parse it simply with a `while/case` loop.

```
$ getopt -n "$0" -o t:Rf -- -Rf file1 -t/mybackup file2
 -R -f -t '/mybackup' -- 'file1' 'file2'
```

You'd typically use it as:

```
parsed_options=$(
  getopt -n "$0" -o t:Rf -- "$@"
) || exit
eval "set -- $parsed_options"
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
  case $1 in
    (-[Rf]) shift;;
    (-t) shift 2;;
    (--) shift; break;;
    (*) exit 1 # should never be reached.
  esac
done
echo "Now, the arguments are $*"
```

Also note that that `getopt` will parse options the same way as GNU `cp` does. In particular, it supports the long options (and entering them abbreviated) and honours the `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variables (which when set disables support for options after arguments) the same way GNU `cp` does.

Note that using gdb and printing the arguments that `getopt_long()` receives can help building the parameters to `getopt(1)`:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  getopt_long (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdae8, options=0x4171a6 "abdfHilLnprst:uvxPRS:T", long_options=0x417c20, opt_index=0x0) at getopt1.c:64
(gdb) set print pretty on
(gdb) p *long_options@40
$10 = {{
    name = 0x4171fb "archive",
    has_arg = 0,
    flag = 0x0,
    val = 97
  }, {
    name = 0x417203 "attributes-only",
[...]
```

Then you can use `getopt` as:

```
getopt -n cp -o abdfHilLnprst:uvxPRS:T -l archive... -- "$@"
```

Remember that GNU `cp`'s list of supported options may change from one version to the next and that `getopt` will not be able to check if you pass a legal value to the `--sparse` option for instance.

Comment: @all: thanks for your replies. @Stephane: is there a reason you are using `while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]` i.o. just `while (($#))`? Is it just to avoid a bashism?

Comment: Yes, though `(($#))` is more a _kshism_.

Answer (score 1):

So every time `getopts` processes an argument it doesn't expect it sets the shell variable `$OPTIND` to the next number in the argument list which it should process and returns other than 0. If `$OPTIND` is set to a value of 1, `getopts` is POSIX-specified to accept a new argument list. So this just watches `getopts` return, saves increments a counter plus `$OPTIND`'s for any failed return, shifts away the failed arguments, and resets `$OPTIND` every failed try.  You can use it like `opts "$@"` - though you'd want to customize the `case` loop or else save it into a variable and change that section to `eval $case`.

```
opts() while getopts :Rt:f opt || {
             until command shift "$OPTIND" || return 0
                   args=$args' "${'"$((a=${a:-0}+$OPTIND))"'}"'
                   [ -n "${1#"${1#-}"}" ]
             do OPTIND=1; done 2>/dev/null; continue
};     do case "$opt"  in
             R) Rflag=1      ;;
             t) tflag=1      ;
                targ=$OPTARG ;;
             f) fflag=1      ;;
       esac; done
```

While running it sets `$args` to every argument which `getopts` did not handle... so...

```
set -- -R file1 -t /mybackup file2 -f
args= opts "$@"; eval "set -- $args"
printf %s\\n "$args"
printf %s\\n "$@"         
printf %s\\n "$Rflag" "$tflag" "$fflag" "$targ"
```

#### OUTPUT

```
 "${2}" "${5}"
file1
file2
1
1
1
/mybackup
```

This works in `bash`, `dash`, `zsh`,`ksh93`, `mksh`... well, I quit trying at that point. In every shell it also got `$[Rtf]flag` and `$targ`. The point is that all of the numbers for the arguments that `getopts` didn't want to process remained.

Changing the options style made no difference either. It worked like `-Rf -t/mybackup` or `-R -f -t /mybackup`. It worked in the middle of the list, at the end of the list, or at the head of the list...

Still, the *very best way* is just to stick a `--` for end of options on your arg list and then do `shift "$(($OPTIND-1))"` at the end of a `getopts` processing run. That way you remove all processed parameters *and* keep the tail end of the argument list.

One thing I like to do is translate long options to short -- and I do that in a very similar way which is why this answer came easily -- *before* I run `getopts`.

```
i=0
until [ "$((i=$i+1))" -gt "$#" ]
do case "$1"                   in
--Recursive) set -- "$@" "-R"  ;;
--file)      set -- "$@" "-f"  ;;
--target)    set -- "$@" "-t"  ;;
*)           set -- "$@" "$1"  ;;
esac; shift; done
```

Comment: Your long option converting would also convert non-options (as `cp -t --file foo` or `cp -- --file foo`) and would not cope with options entered abbreviated (`--fi`...), or with the `--target=/dest` syntax.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - the long converting thing is only an example - it obviously hasn't been built up very well. I replaced the `getopts` thing with a much simpler function.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - please look again. While the long option comment remains justified, the first - and its accompanying downvote - no longer is, as I think. Also, I think `opts()` has some bearing on your own answer as `opts()` works in a single loop - touching each argument but once - and does so reliably *(as near as I can tell)*, portably, and without a single subshell.

Comment: resetting OPTIND is what I call starting another getopts loop. In effect, that's parsing several command lines/sets of options (`-R`, `-t /mybackup`, `-f`). I'll keep my down vote for now as it's still obfuscated, you're using `$a` uninitialised, and `args= opts...` is likely to leave `args` unset (or set to what it was before) after `opts` returns in many shells (that includes bash).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - that does include `bash` - I hate that. In my opinion, if the function is a *current shell* function that should be retained. I'm addressing these things - as the current function, with more tests, could robustly be made to handle all cases, and even to *flag* argument with its preceding option, but I disagree that it is *obfuscated*. As written, it is the *most simple* and *most direct* means of accomplishing its task that I can think of. `test`ing then `shift`ing makes little sense when in every failed `shift` case you should `return`. It is not intended to do otherwise.