# Passing options to subcommands in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, options

I'm scripting a sequence of commands I used to enter by hand. The rough outline goes something like this

```
$ echo ${FILENAME_ARGS} | some | big | pipeline | sort -options | etc >temp
$ gs -OptionsThatNeverChange `cat temp`
```

Basically, the only thing that changes between runs are the options passed to sort and the files contained in FILENAME_ARGS.

What I want to do is be able to type something like

```
$ do-thing -some -options *.pdf
```

and have all of the `-whatever` go to the options for sort, while all of the `*.pdf` go into FILENAME_ARGS. To do this I need a way to pick out all of the things that start with a `-` from `$@`. Is there some simple way to pull options out of the arguments passed to a shell script?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035 -- How can I handle command-line arguments (options) to my script easily?

Comment: Option parsing is a very FAQ. The wooledge link from @jordanm is a great resource.  See also [this related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20975/9537).

Comment: @jw013: This isn't about option parsing so much as option extraction. I just want to pass the options to sort and put the rest of the arguments somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo ${FILENAME_ARGS} | grep -e - | sort >options
echo ${FILENAME_ARGS} | grep -v -e - >files
```

Answer (score 2):

In your shoes, I'd write a script that takes all of your arguments and assigns them as variables, then execute the | very | long | pipe with the argument variables dropped in where necessary, i.e.

```
$ ./wrapper.sh -a firstoption -b secondoption -c thirdoption

$ cat wrapper.sh

#!/bin/bash

#trap variables with case statement here
for arg in "$@" ; do
    case "$arg" in
      -a)
        alpha=$2
        shift
        ;;
      -b)
        bravo=$2
        shift
        ;;
      -c)
        charlie=$2
        shift
        ;;
     esac
done
# at this point: $alpha=firstoption
#                $bravo=secondoption
#                $charlie=thirdoption

echo "Better grab a coffee man, this could take a while...."
echo "STUFF" | some $alpha $bravo | big -c $bravo -Z $charlie | pipeline -yx $charlie $alpha $bravo| sort -N $charlie -options | etc.${bravo}.${alpha} >temp.${charlie}
```