# how to declare command line variables in shell scripts?

Tags: shell-script

I want to declare the variable as a command line argument for a shell script just like

**./script.sh**

```
file=/tmp/domains.txt 
domain=abcd.com**
```

help to do the same.

Comment: which shell are you using?  for most shells you can put `file=/tmp/domains.txt` and `domain=abcd.com` in a separate file then include it into your script with `source whateverfilname`.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass these variables by specifying them *before* the command name; e.g.

```
file=/tmp/domains.txt domain=abcd.com ./script.sh
```

By doing it like this these variables are put into the environment before the shell script is run, meaning that you can use these in the shell script just like any other variables.

Answer (score 1):

Passing variables like this works but requires the user to understand the internals of your script.  It can also cause weird, seemingly inexplicable behavior if the variables happen to be defined in the environment for some other reason entirely unrelated to your script (and the user forgets to set them on the command line when running your script).

A better way to do it is to use the shell's built-in option parsing, `getopts`.  For example:

```
usage() {
    # print some help text here, e.g.
    echo Usage:
    echo "      $0 [-f filename] [-d domainname]"
}

# -f and -d are the only valid options and they both
# take strings as arguments.
while getopts f:d: opt; do
  case "$opt" in
     f) file="$OPTARG" ;;
     d) domain="$OPTARG" ;;
     *) usage ; exit 1 ;;
  esac
done
shift $(expr $OPTIND - 1)

# print help message and exit if either file or domain are
# empty.
[ -z "$file" ] && usage && exit 1
[ -z "$domain" ] && usage && exit 1
```

See your shell's man page (e.g. `man bash` or `man dash`) for more details.  bash's built in `help` command also provides useful info about `getopts` - i.e. `help getopts`

If you want to be able to use GNU-style long options (e.g. `--file`, `--domain`) as well as the short `-f` and `-d`, you could use the `getopt` program from the `util-linux` package.  Note that that's `getopt` without an "s", while the built-in is `getopts` with an "s".

I usually use the util-linux `getopt` because I like to be able to have --long options....but `getopts` is standard and doesn't require anything extra to be installed because it's built in to every posix compatible shell, and will work with bash, dash, ksh etc.

Comment: see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20975/how-do-i-handle-switches-in-a-shell-script