# How to pass args into scripts?

Tags: getopts

I am trying to pass arg to this scripts but it does not work anyone knows how fix this ? and I do not want to use args i want to use getopts

For This part

```
# Get command line parameters
i=
a=
y=
while getopts iay: name
        case $name in
                i) i="$OPTARG" ;;
                a) a="$OPTARG" ;;
                y) y="$OPTARG" ;;
        ?) exit;;
        esac
done
```

### This is the scripts

```
if [ $# -ne 3 ]
        then
                echo -e "\nUsage: mortgage rate amount period\n"
                exit 1
        fi
# Get command line parameters
i=
a=
y=
while getopts iay: name
        case $name in
                i) i="$OPTARG" ;;
                a) a="$OPTARG" ;;
                y) y="$OPTARG" ;;
        ?) exit;;
        esac
done

# Compute the monthly payment
x=$(echo "scale=20;1+$i/200" | bc)
z=$(echo "scale=20;1/6" | bc)
x2z=$(echo "scale=20;e($z*l($x))" | bc -l)
y12=$(echo "scale=20;-$y*12" | bc)
x2z2y12=$(echo "scale=20;e($y12*l($x2z))" | bc -l)
p=$(echo "scale=3;$a*(($x2z-1))/(1-$x2z2y12)" | bc)

# Print the monthly payment
echo $p
exit 0
```

==========================
This is original scripts:

```
if [ $# -ne 3 ] then echo -e "\nUsage: mortgage rate amount period\n" exit 1 fi

Get command line parameters

i=$1; a=$2; y=$3

Compute the monthly payment

x=$(echo "scale=20;1+$i/200" | bc) z=$(echo "scale=20;1/6" | bc) x2z=$(echo "scale=20;e($z*l($x))" | bc -l) y12=$(echo "scale=20;-$y*12" | bc) x2z2y12=$(echo "scale=20;e($y12*l($x2z))" | bc -l) p=$(echo "scale=3;$a*(($x2z-1))/(1-$x2z2y12)" | bc)

Print the monthly payment

echo $p exit 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Arguments of a shell script are just $1, $2, $3 and so on. For example, put echo $2; echo $1 in a script.sh file, make it executable, and run it as ./script.sh one two.

In your script;

`i=$1`

`a=$2`

`y=$3`

and run it as `./myscript.sh 3 4 23`. Now i will be 3, a will be 4 and y will be 23.

Comment: it was already like that I am trying to change it

it was like this :::::::::

if [ $# -ne 3 ] then echo -e "\nUsage: mortgage rate amount period\n" exit 1 fi

Get command line parameters

i=$1; a=$2; y=$3

Compute the monthly payment

x=$(echo "scale=20;1+$i/200" | bc) z=$(echo "scale=20;1/6" | bc) x2z=$(echo "scale=20;e($z*l($x))" | bc -l) y12=$(echo "scale=20;-$y*12" | bc) x2z2y12=$(echo "scale=20;e($y12*l($x2z))" | bc -l) p=$(echo "scale=3;$a*(($x2z-1))/(1-$x2z2y12)" | bc)

Print the monthly payment

echo $p exit 0

Answer (score 2):

You've only told `getopts` that `-y` has an argument.  You're also missing the "do" from the "while" command.

You also don't need to check that the number of args is 3 any more - in fact, there won't be 3 args, there will be 6.  But arg counting is the wrong method to use with getopts.  Instead, check that your required variables all have a value.

Try

```
#! /bin/sh

usage() {
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "       $0 -i rate -a amount -y period"
    exit 1
} 

i='' ; a='' ; y=''

while getopts i:a:y: name ; do
    case $name in
            i) i="$OPTARG" ;;
            a) a="$OPTARG" ;;
            y) y="$OPTARG" ;;
            *) usage ;;
    esac
done
shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))

if [ -z "$i" ] || [ -z "$a" ] || [ -z "$y" ] ; then 
    usage
fi

# Compute the monthly payment
x=$(echo "scale=20;1+$i/200" | bc)
z=$(echo "scale=20;1/6" | bc)
x2z=$(echo "scale=20;e($z*l($x))" | bc -l)
y12=$(echo "scale=20;-$y*12" | bc)
x2z2y12=$(echo "scale=20;e($y12*l($x2z))" | bc -l)
p=$(echo "scale=3;$a*(($x2z-1))/(1-$x2z2y12)" | bc)

# Print the monthly payment
echo $p
exit 0
```

Comment: I did change it to this

i=
a=
y=
while getopts i:a:y: name ; do
        case $name in
                i) i="$OPTARG" ;;
                a) a="$OPTARG" ;;
                y) y="$OPTARG" ;;
        ?) exit;;
        esac
done
shift $(( OPTIND - 1))

But did not work

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20975/how-do-i-handle-switches-in-a-shell-script

Comment: what, exactly, do you mean by "did not work"?  FYI you can use `set -x` in a sh script to help debugging

Comment: when i change it the scripts does not work it means it did not pass value to the  options

Comment: still not working

Comment: "not working" is probably the most useless error report ever.  provide details.  in particular, provide details on a) what is going wrong and b) what you are doing that differs from what i wrote above.

Comment: BTW, the script in my answer is tested and works.  At least, the option parsing works - i have no idea if your calculations are correct because i didn't even look at those. but as far as parsing the options and setting the variables - that works exactly as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I Find answer Thinks to everyone who helped

this is code:

```
# Use “getopts” to give options to the script
while getopts "i:a:y:" option; do
case $option in
i)
i=$OPTARG
;;
a)
a=$OPTARG
;;
y)
y=$OPTARG
;;
\?)
echo -e "\nUsage: mortgage rate amount period\n"
exit 1
;;
esac
done

# Compute the monthly payment
x=$(echo "scale=20;1+$i/200" | bc)
z=$(echo "scale=20;1/6" | bc)
x2z=$(echo "scale=20;e($z*l($x))" | bc -l)
y12=$(echo "scale=20;-$y*12" | bc)
x2z2y12=$(echo "scale=20;e($y12*l($x2z))" | bc -l)
p=$(echo "scale=3;$a*(($x2z-1))/(1-$x2z2y12)" | bc)

# Print the monthly payment
Echo “Your Monthly is $p”
exit 0
```