# how to add custom arguments to commands

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

So how would you and extra arguments to a custom bash script like "Nmap -p"

I've tried doing research on the subject bit nothing comes up

Comment: [This link](https://medium.com/introduction-into-bash/bash-scripts-part-3-command-line-options-and-switches-97f1f3a30334) should get you pointed in the right direction. Otherwise, there's stuff like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20975/how-do-i-handle-switches-in-a-shell-script).

Comment: thanks a lot this really helped

Comment: I figured it would. It's not too difficult to add them. To find links, I used "bash scripting +options +switches". I was going to write a quick tutorial, but figured it was better done elsewhere and I'm *really* not the best person to write such things. There are others that are far more adept than I am. Good luck!