# How bash getopts knows what arguments the call has

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, getopts

If `getopts` is a bash function, by my understanding, you need to pass `$@` - the whole arguments to `getopts` to let the function know what kind of arguments you have in order to proceed, right?

It seems to me that you don't need it, so how the `getopts` get to know what arguments I have in the current scope? Does it have a way to trace the previous call like the other high-level languages do?

```
while getopts abcde opt; do
              ˄˄˄˄˄ <-- you only need to pass the argument labels here, 
                        how getopts knows what arguments I have
    case $opt in
        ...
    esac
done
```

Comment: `shift` and `set` (well and `.`, `eval` (well and `command` when called as `command shift/eval...`)) are other shell builtins that can access/modify positional parameters. `read`, `readarray`, `typeset`, `unset`, `[`, `printf` are examples of shell builtins which like `getopts` can access/modify shell variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getopts` is a shell built-in, so it can reference `$@` directly. It also sets the shell variables `OPTARG` and `OPTIND`. (Note that inside a function, `getopts` will reference that function's `$@` rather than the global arguments. You should localise `OPTIND` if you want a repeatable (odempotent) function call.)

The synopsis (summary) is

> **`getopts optstring name [arg ...]`**

and the description is such that,

> `getopts`  is used by shell procedures to parse positional parameters. `optstring` contains the option characters to be recognized; if a character is followed  by a colon, the option is expected to have an argument, which should be separated from it by white space.

Note that (at least) the `bash` documentation (`man bash`) also notes,

> `getopts` normally  parses  the positional parameters, but if more arguments are supplied as arg values, `getopts` parses those instead.

References

- [How do I handle switches in a shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20977/100397)

Comment: If its passible for us to write a function which can reference $@ directly???

Comment: @Till of course. `printf '%s\n' "$@"` references `$@` directly, for example

Comment: umm, i dont geit it. If I do `printf '%s\n' "$@"` in function `Foo`, it wont display the `$@` which where called `Foo` but only display whatever passed to `Foo`

Comment: Yes that's right. Ask a new question about referencing the global `$@` in a function and let me know, and I'll answer it there for you. Or someone else might

Comment: sure! I will do it, but it limits one post in every 40 mins, I will post you a link later, thank you very much!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/761988/how-to-referencing-without-pass-it-in-bash-function  Thank you for your help!